# How to keep linux machine shutdown for fixed duration

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to simulate a condition for a Test case were linux server is down for 10 minutes. I am aware how to shutdown the machine but it will auto restart if I issue `reboot` command. Currently I am using following way to keep `target` down for 600 sec.  but it is not robust as sometimes it lead target to partially come up before another reboot. leading to incorrect result.

```
target="active001"
secs=600  ;SECONDS=0 ; 
while (( SECONDS < secs )); 
do
  ssh ${target}  reboot
  sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: `halt` should shutdown it forever. Problem is to run it again. Some computers have function `wake-on-lan` so you can start it remotly but it may works on local LAN.

Comment: Is your server a VM? If so, do you have access to the hypervisor? If not, do you have access to the hardware? The simple answer to your question is to use `shutdown` rather than `reboot`, but then you need something to bring back the machine 10 minutes later.

Comment: Maybe just shut down networking on the linux server for a duration?

Comment: You can enable autoboot in BIOS, then use an electronic switch (domotic) to put ON the shutdown distro (if you have a hardware box)

Comment: `ssh $target 'bash -c "sudo if down; sleep 600; sudo if up" &'` where `if` is your distro's distro's interface command for manipulating the network devices.

Comment: If you want to be *sure* it's down, the best answer doesn't involve software at all. If this is a physical hardware device, buy a networked power switch -- they're used all the time for STONITH operations ("Shoot The Other Node In The Head", an operation to prevent clusters in a split-brain state from causing data corruption).

Comment: ...as a sysadmin with high-value data on volumes that multiple systems have a path to write to, I'd *never* trust a script that requires the OS layer to be well-behaved to mediate in conflicts -- the set of cases where you need it to work is strongly correlated to the set of cases where it *won't*.

Comment: ...whereas if a box just needs to *look* down? Don't reboot it at all -- just leave it running but kill the network; since it's still up, it has precise control over timing.

Comment: thank you all for your Guidance , its a VM . will use hypervisor commands to shut down the instance and bring it back . This is not exactly what I was searching but  now I understand this is what possible using `sw`

Comment: I have voted to close this question as I am not sure how value add it would be

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...<3600
STATUS="active001"
TARGET_SECOND="600"

TARGET_TIME=$(($(date +%M)+$TARGET_SECOND))
TARGET_TIME_UP=$(($(date +%s)+$TARGET_SECOND))
START_TIME=$(date +%s)

printf "\033[01;35mStarting Schedhule Reboot if need... \033[01;32mInterval ($(date -d @$TARGET_TIME +%M) Minute)\033[01;00m\n"    
while true; do
    TIME_NOW=$(date +%s)    
    DELTATIME=$(($TARGET_TIME_UP - $TIME_NOW))    
    TIMELAPSE=$(date -ud "@$DELTATIME" +'%H:%M:%S')    
    if [ $TIME_NOW = $TARGET_TIME_UP ];then 
        #printf "\nRunning script command...\n"
        ssh ${STATUS} reboot
        #end loop or other option
        break
    fi
    printf "\r$(date -d @$TIME_NOW +%H:%M:%S) \033[01;32mReboot Execute on: \033[01;32m$(date -d @$TARGET_TIME_UP +%H:%M:%S)\033[00;00m [ ELAPSED : $TIMELAPSE ] "
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: How is this going to work better than the OP's existing code?